# UIImageView Animation Images, find out which image is showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have UIImageView which display images via animation. Please see code below

```
NSArray *images = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Banner1.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Banner2.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Banner3.png"], nil];
    BannerImageView.animationImages = images;
    BannerImageView.animationDuration = 9;

    [BannerImageView startAnimating];
```

Now I would like to know which image is on display when I touch on UIImageView(or transparent button which add on top of UIImageView)

```
- (IBAction)BannerPressed:(id)sender {

[BannerImageView stopAnimating];
NSLog(@"How would i know what image currently showing on BannerView");}
```

Please help me to find answer!

Comment: Check whether this is useful for u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17848438/determine-which-of-its-animationimages-a-uiimageview-is-displaying

Comment: Thank you HRM but that did not help! get error on This line    NSTimeInterval elapsed = - 1 * [startDate timeIntervalSinceNow];

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Requirement has been change!! will keep you posted with my answer!